# Please help with Parsing Expected ',' but got ';'

Tags: solidity, blockchain, error, visual-studio-code

I have looked far and wide for a solution and have read solidity documentation. Please help me find the parsing error in the code.

Thanks in advance.

```
var KiwiCoinSale = artifacts.require('KiwiCoinSale');

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(KiwiCoin, 1000000).then(function() {
    // Token price is 0.001 Ether
    var tokenPrice = 1000000000000000;
    return deployer.deploy(KiwiCoinSale, KiwiCoin.address, tokenPrice);
  } **<Error arrives here>**  **')' Expected)**
```

```
 function endSale() public {
        require(msg.sender == admin);
        require(condition);(tokenContract.transfer(admin, tokenContract.balanceOf(address(this))); **Errors arrives here** **Expected ',' but got ';'**
```

Comment: Hi there. Your Solidity code has no formatting. If you lay the code out with correct indentation, correct termination (i.e. `;`) and matching brackets and curly braces, then this type of problem doesn't arise. You should look into how you can improve your workflow and tooling: find an editor that has a compatible prettifier or linter, syntax highlighting, and install a bracket-matcher add-on. (I thought VSC already had one...)

Comment: @RichardHorrocks I thought so too and have tried rewriting the code aswell as switching over to Remix yet the problem persists. Hence my post on here to find a resolution

Comment: Add full contract text to question